# Dynamically set Data Source path in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically set the file path name for an Excel data source file in Tableau?

The issue is that I have multiple connections to multiple files that reside within a Dropbox folder. At anyone time, 2 or more people are making changes to the Tableau file. This means that in order to refresh the data (via a live connection), each user has to redirect the path of each data connection to match their machine. eg `C:\Users\**user1**\Dropbox\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsx` gets changed to `C:\Users\**user2**\Dropbox\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsx`

What I was wanting to do is make this process easier, as multiple connection mean I have to do this half a dozen times each time I open the Tableau file. Something like `"C:\Users\" & **myDynamicUser** & "\Dropbox\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsx "` is what I was thinking.

Is this possible and if not, can you offer an alternative solution?

Thanks

Comment: Won't help you right now, but in v10 they've added Document API which will allow you to modify data sources programmatically. http://www.tableau.com/coming-soon

Comment: Yeah - super excited for v10 and have been playing around with the beta version. Unfortunately, it will be a while until we can roll it out here seeing as we are still stuck with v8 servers due to clients security concerns